# Why appcmd.exe does not allow to set ipSecurity allowUnlisted?

Tags: powershell, iis, appcmd, ip-restrictions

I would like to set ip restriction to the /admin folder on my website with PowerShell.

I do understand, that because this section is locked I have to go to applicationHost.config, and unless I unlock I can not use local web.config in that particular folder. 
I also figured out how can I add an IP restriction rule using appcmd.exe.

Because of allowUnlisted is true (Allow) by default, I also have to set it false, which I can not accomplish, because when I use the following command I got error:

```
$location = "My Site/admin"
appcmd.exe set config $location -section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity /allowUnlisted:false
```

> ERROR ( message:Can not set attribute "allowUnlisted" to value "false".. Reason: This configuration section cannot be used at this
>   path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level.

I also discovered that there is appcmd lock/unlock facility, but those commands does not allow a specific location. I do not want to change anything expect my $locations behavior, and do this in applicationHost.config.

Which is **completely possible using the GUI**, in IIS Manager using the IP Restrictions on my particuar admin folder in Edit feature I can set it to Deny, and that adds to the end of applicationHost.config the following lines (no other changes):

```
<location path="My Site/admin">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
                <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true" />
            </ipSecurity>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

**Question**

How can I do this change in applicationHost.config with CLI way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about using appcmd.exe. However, if you want to use the powerShell WebAdministration module, then you can use the following:

```
$location = "My Site/Admin"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location $location -filter "system.webServer/security/ipSecurity" -name "allowUnlisted" -value "False"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. I was looking somewhere Set-IISConfigAttributeValue and similar, but was so overcomplicated I could not figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Add /commit:

```
.\appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity /allowUnlisted:'false'  /commit:apphost
```

If you want to do it using appcmd